# Perl processing in java

Tags: java, regex, perl

I have to do some file processing(retrieve some value from a file and return it) in java.I can easily do this in Perl.I have written a perl script but i am unable to run it from java file.

Can anybody please help me as to how to run it or if i can do this in java alone.

My java code which calls perl script is:

```
while ((output = responseBuffer.readLine()) != null) {

    if(output.contains(hidden_tag)){
      String toRun = "perl PatternSearch.pl "+ output;
      Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(toRun);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the Perl Script? And what have you tried in Java? (We need resources to analyze and answer your question).

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: What value, how is it retrieved? If a regex, does it match on several lines? etc etc

Comment: And does your perl script invoke python or ruby too.

Comment: while ((output = responseBuffer.readLine()) != null) {
    
    if(output.contains(hidden_tag)){
     String toRun = "perl PatternSearch.pl "+ output;
     Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(toRun);
     
    }
    
   }

Comment: Do NOT put that in a comment but edit your question instead

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean here, but if the "value to retrieve" is done using regexes, I have just [completed a project](https://github.com/fge/largetext) allowing to use regexes on large text files (max 2 GiB approximately, due to the `int` limit of a `CharSequence`):

```
private static final LargeTextFactory FACTORY
    = LargeTextFactory.defaultFactory();

public List<String> getMatchesForPattern(final Path file, final String re)
    throws IOException
{
    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re);
    final List<String> ret = new ArrayList<>();

    try (
        final LargeText text = FACTORY.fromPath(file);
    ) {
        final Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
        while (m.find())
            ret.add(m.group());
        return ret;
    }
}
```

No need to use perl anymore ;) Except if you use perl-specific regex features, of course

---

Final note: if your input is structured, ie an HTML input etc, you are better off using a dedicated library; for HTML, that would be jsoup for instance.

Comment: Java has many regex deficiencies.

Comment: @sin cite one... They work pretty well as far as I'm concerned. Of course, they are not a builtin part of the language like perl

Comment: I would set up [the perl script as a CGI](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html) and access it using [Apache HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/) as a web service. If you would like further assistance, post your code and I'd be happy to expand this into an answer.

Comment: For Java7: recursion, conditionals, \g named/numbered backrefs,  branch reset, named uni char. Java 6 has a few more.

Comment: "Input is structured" - do you mean if the regular expression needs to be able to count or otherwise keep state?

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the answers.I was able to solve my problem using java.util.regex.pattern and matcher.Below is the java code,in case anybody else needs it :)

            String pattern = "^\t*(<input type=\"hidden\" name=)(.*)(value =)(.*)(>$)";
   String hiddenKey = null;
   String hiddenValue = null;
   
   Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

   Matcher m = r.matcher(output);
   
   if (m.find()) {
    hiddenKey = m.group(2);
    hiddenValue = m.group(4);
    hiddenHashMap.put(hiddenKey, hiddenValue);
   }

Comment: @sin if you need a whole grammar, in Java, you won't use regexes; you will use something like, said, parboiled, antlr or javacc. Or a dedicated library for the particular file format.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen bad wording; I really mean that if a dedicated package exists for this or that format (HTML, XML, CSV, etc etc) you are better off using a dedicated library than regexes. I mean, even perl has `HTML::Parser`

Comment: @fge - Don't know what you mean. What in my list made you think whole grammar. Recursion is a misnomer, its just a function call. Those items mentioned are a very big deal.